# How to add items to XAML/WINRT Grid from Code

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, grid, windows-runtime

So, I am trying to create a grid that can be dynamically populated by 0 to X items depending on when the Frame is open.

I read the MSDN article on how to create a grid and add to it in code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx

Howeverm I want to create the Grid in the XAML and add to it in the code.  Something like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ManagePhotosContent" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
<!-- to be filled in by code -->
</Grid>
```

In C# code i am doing something like this:

```
rowDef = new RowDefinition();
ManagePhotosContent.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
textBlock = new TextBlock();

// i is an incrementer
textBlock.Text = string.Format("The is iteration {0}, i);
ManagePhotosContent.SetRow(textBlock, i);
```

However, SetRow is not an available function or property of the ManagePhotosContent grid that I created in XAML.  Further, I am unable to see how to set up the RowDefinition in code to be of Height="*".  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Isn't SetRow is a static method on Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
ManagePhotosContent.SetRow(textBlock, i);
```

with

```
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, i);
```

`SetRow` is a static method of `Grid` class and therefore cannot be used on object instance. To set [`RowDefinition.Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.rowdefinition.height) use that:

```
row.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```