# Adding controls to XAML Page by code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a XAML page with this body:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
</Grid>
```

Now I want to add following controls in the Code Behind into the `ContentPanel`

```
    <ViewportControl x:Name="viewport" ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted" ViewportChanged="viewport_ViewportChanged">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
            <Image x:Name="TestImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" CacheMode="BitmapCache" ImageOpened="OnImageOpened">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="xform"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </Canvas>
    </ViewportControl>
```

Is there a way to do this by code?

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990624/wpf-add-controls-from-code)

Comment: try this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761810/how-to-add-items-to-xaml-winrt-grid-from-code) if it helps you

Comment: @Leparevilo, which bits are having problem with?

Comment: @Leparevilo tell us what you have tried. Did you even google this? A simple search turns up lots of help. Try googling "wpf add control from code"

Comment: I have Trouble, "converting" the XAML-code to C#-code. Creating the `ViewportControl` is OK. Creating the `Canvas`is OK. But creating the `Image`and it´s "transform-stuff" - here I´m unable to code this.

Comment: @Leparevilo do you need these names (`x:Name`) elsewhere in XAML?

Comment: No. In my try to create controls in code, I use the Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

> Creating the ViewportControl is OK. Creating the Canvas is OK. But creating the Image and it's "transform-stuff" - here I'm unable to code this

and you don't need to register names you can try this to create `Image`:

```
var img = new Image
{
    RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0,0),
    CacheMode = new BitmapCache(),
    RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform()
};
img.ImageOpened += OnImageOpened;

//and you add it to Canvas
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(img);
```

Comment: This seems to work. Can you finally help me, to add the canvas to the ViewportControl?

Comment: `VieportControl` is a `ContentControl` so setting the `Content` like `viewPortControl.Content = canvas` should work